# I would like to run load-file in a sandboxed namespace in clojure

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm new to Clojure and for fun/education I'm writing a generic migration framework for lein. One thing this system has to do is read a clojure file from the disk, then run either the `up` function, or the `down` function. I figure this file should probably be evaluated in a temporary namespace but I'm having trouble getting that to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
(def user-namespace (create-ns 'leiningen.generic-migrate.user-eval))

(defn load-migration-file [file]
  (binding [*ns* user-namespace]
    (load-file (.getAbsolutePath file))
    (keys (ns-publics *ns*))))
```

This gives me the error:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: defn in this context
```

My question is, what's the best approach for using load-file, then running a defined function, without risk of someone overwriting stuff in my namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defmacro with-ns
  "Evaluates body in another namespace.  ns is either a namespace
  object or a symbol.  This makes it possible to define functions in
  namespaces other than the current one."
  [ns & body]
  `(binding [*ns* (the-ns ~ns)]
     ~@(map (fn [form] `(eval '~form)) body)))

(defmacro with-temp-ns
  "Evaluates body in an anonymous namespace, which is then immediately
  removed.  The temporary namespace will 'refer' clojure.core."
  [& body]
  `(try
     (create-ns 'sym#)
     (let [result# (with-ns 'sym#
                     (clojure.core/refer-clojure)
                     ~@body)]
       result#)
     (finally (remove-ns 'sym#))))
```